# LPNMITEMACTIVATE and code analysis (C26462)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis

Why is it that in the source code in the SDK for [`LPNMITEMACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmitemactivate) it is defined with the asterix to the **left**?

```
typedef struct tagNMITEMACTIVATE
{
    NMHDR   hdr;
    int     iItem;
    int     iSubItem;
    UINT    uNewState;
    UINT    uOldState;
    UINT    uChanged;
    POINT   ptAction;
    LPARAM  lParam;
    UINT    uKeyFlags;
} NMITEMACTIVATE, *LPNMITEMACTIVATE;
```

I am always used to the pointer being on the **right**. Either way, code like:

```
const LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItem = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
```

Will still flag a const ([C26462](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26462?view=msvc-160)) warning:

[image]

If I change the code to:

```
const NMITEMACTIVATE* pNMItem = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
```

The warning will go away.

Comment: [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations). Not entirely accurate, but a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this with Visual Studio 2022, first of all, warning C26462 was not enabled by default. Perhaps you are using an earlier release, or there is something odd with my installation.

After manually enabling the warning, I could make that warning go away by assigning `pNMItem` more than once:

```
LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItem = nullptr;
pNMItem = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
```

How is this useful?

Or it can be fixed as suggested in other answers. But you may have additional problem because `pNMHDR` was probably declared as `LPNMHDR`, so you have to rewrite more lines:

```
NMHDR hdr = { 0 };
const NMHDR* pNMHDR = reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(&hdr);
const NMITEMACTIVATE* pNMItem = reinterpret_cast<const NMITEMACTIVATE*>(pNMHDR);
```

This can be a big waste of time. Note, the extra compliance is recommended if you are writing code that's supposed to run on any system. But MFC is tied to Windows so this isn't really an issue. MFC and Windows are still using that "long pointer" crap that's left over from 16-bit Windows, they are not compliant themselves, so consider turning off some of these warnings.

Comment: I see. I am include to just leave these warnings as they are then. I have it set up to suppress all SDK warnings (using External Includes setting). It is just my code .... So I won't worry about this too much. But i will continue with my progress through my files to get the castings revised annd ways I use the memory improved.

Comment: That's a good plan to just make your own code as compliant as possible, not worry about code analysis warnings for Windows/MFC headers. Personally I would leave it at default settings. I think that particular warning C26462 is supposed to be off by default. This is the pre-release VS2022, maybe they are still thinkering with the settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard C/C++

Like in this (not runnable) code snippet:

```
typedef int *LPINT;
//  typedef int* LPINT;  // you could write this, it's exactly the
                         // the same as above

int main()
{
  LPINT pint;
  int* pint2;

  *pint = *pint2;
}
```

`pint` and `pint2` are both pointers to `int`. BTW this is hiding a pointer type behind a typedef, which is a bad idea (but was considered as a good idea in old MS days), but lots of Microsoft headers still have these `typedef sometype *LPsometype;` typedefs for compatibility reasons.

Another example which is closer to the MS header you're refering to:

This:

```
typedef struct tagNMITEMACTIVATE
{
  int   hdr;
  int     iItem;
} NMITEMACTIVATE, *LPNMITEMACTIVATE;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
typedef struct tagNMITEMACTIVATE
{
  int   hdr;
  int     iItem;
} NMITEMACTIVATE;

typedef struct tagNMITEMACTIVATE *LPNMITEMACTIVATE;
```

Comment: I understand that part. But the definition of `LPNMITEMACTIVATE` is `*NMITEMACTIVATE`. I would **never** declare a pointer that way. Either way, code analysis is saying I have not set the pointer as `const` when I have. And the warnign will only stop when I stop using `LPNMITEMACTIVATE`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle ok, I was answering the _"Why is it that in the source code in the SDK for LPNMITEMACTIVATE it is defined with the asterix to the left?"_ part of the question. Maybe you should modify the question a bit. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: Technically your answer doesn't explain to me why the asterix is on the left. I know it is there as I put the structure in my question. What I am trying to clear up is why the code analysis warning would not go away. And I wondered if it was because the LP version of the pointer had the * to the left rather than the right. It was a hunch.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Modified. Does this answer the "asterix to the left" question?

Comment: For arguments say, would you ever decalare a pointer to an `int` like this: `*int my_int_pointer;` ? Is that perfectly valid?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle `*int my_int_pointer;` is of course invalid, but in the MS header you show there is no such declaration.

Comment: It shown: `NMITEMACTIVATE, *LPNMITEMACTIVATE`. **Why** is it written that way? My not: `NMITEMACTIVATE, LPNMITEMACTIVATE*` ???

Comment: I get it now. Still don't know why code analysis would still flag it.

Answer (score 1):

For pointer const can be applied to the type the pointer points at:

```c
const NMITEMACTIVATE* p;
```

or

```c
NMITEMACTIVATE const* p;
```

Or it can be applied to the pointer variable itself:

```c
NMITEMACTIVATE* const p;
```

Now if you have typedef:

```c
typedef NMITEMACTIVATE *PNMITEMACTIVATE;
```

The const would not apply to the type being pointed at. Either way it is the pointer itself is constant:

```
const PNMITEMACTIVATE p;
PNMITEMACTIVATE const p;
```

To avoid this confusion, prefer not to use raw pointer typedefs (and not to define them).